# Athenticating controllers in an MVC framework for PHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter

I am using the codeigniter framework and I am trying to implement the tankauth authentication.  It works well for regular pages.  In the __construct of the controller, I put the

```
if (!authenticated) { redirect('auth'); }
```

there so that it protects all of the functions in the controller.  This works fine if the user's credentials time out and they try to load a new page, it just redirects them to the auth page so they can login again.  However, I get an infinite loop if the function in the controller is called via ajax.  I assume because it is trying to send the redirect headers when the page is already loaded.

What is the correct way to protect ajax calls and redirect the user to the auth page when someone who is no logged in tries to call the function?

Thanks!

Comment: what a horrible way to implement access control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with tankauth in general, so there may be a better way, but in general, instead of calling the redirect from the controller, you need to return a message (e.g. in JSON) and then terminate the script, rather than redirecting.

The client side Javascript that made the Ajax call, then checks the response and if it indicates the user was logged out, use javascript to redirect to the login (`window.location`).  If you send a redirect on a page that was requested via Ajax, it doesn't cause the browser to redirect, the Ajax call simply follows the redirect and the result of the Ajax call is whatever HTML your login page returns.

So it might look like this:

```
if (!authenticated) {
    if (is_ajax_call) {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => 'loggedout'));
        exit;
    } else {
        redirect('auth');
    }
}
```

The the Javascript checks to see if the response contains an `error` key, and if it is `loggedout`, it should redirect the user's browser to your login page.

Comment: Ok, I can see that this would work.  But I was hoping that there would be a cleaner way of doing this.  If I understand correctly, this would require that we add the authentication script to each function and a handler for "errors" in all of the javascript functions.  It would be very nice if there was just something I could put in the __construct that would just force the user to the login page no matter how it is loaded (ajax or otherwise).

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot use ajax to (automatically) redirect the calling page, so you will somehow have to respond to the request, or return no data in the event of an ajax call.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the best method.  What I ended up doing is create a check in all of the javascript ajax calls.  The calls checks to see if the result is the auth page.  If it is, then it just redirects the whole page with window.location like drew010 suggests.  If the page is called normally like a page load rather than ajax, then the system just serves up the redirect and the auth login page is loaded correctly.  This is kind of a hack since it has to load the login page twice if the user is not logged in.